# How to disable sorting on search in elasticsearch using Java API

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a **predefined json format**, which storing into elasticsearch as given below :-

```
"_source": {
           "1111": {
              "Name": "X",
              "Address": [
                 "park street"
              ]
           },
           "3333": {
              "Name": "Y",
              "Address": [
                 "national road"
              ]
           },
           "2222": {
              "Name": "Z",
              "Address": [
                 "miller road"
              ]
           }               
           "4444":{
           "Name": "A","Address":[{"0011":{"Name":"XYZ","Address":["10,lake road"]},
           "0022":{"Name":"ABC","Value":["Spring Apartment"]},}]
           }
     }
```

I used below java code to get the json from elasticsearch.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("INDEXNAME")
            .setTypes("TYPE")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    //.setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("2222.Address", "miller road"))  // Filter
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

But above code returns the sorted json as given below :-

```
           "1111": {
              "Address": [
                 "park street"
              ],
              "Name": "X"

           },
           "2222": {
           "Address": [
                 "miller road"
              ],
              "Name": "Z"

           },   
           "3333": {
           "Address": [
                 "national road"
              ],
              "Name": "Y"

           },   
           "4444":{
           "Address":[{"0011":{"Address":["10,lake road"],"Name":"XYZ"},
           "0022":{"Address":["Spring Apartment"],"Name":"ABC"},}],
           "Name":"A"

           }
```

How to get the same json as stored into elasticsearch using Java API ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ES stores your doucment as JSON. From the docs

> The _source field contains the original JSON document body that was
>   passed at index time

and from [json.org](http://www.json.org/),

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

so you can't get exact key/value pairs in order because json library used by ES will rearrange them.

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier answer stated, by definiton JSON objects' keys are an unordered set and thus implementations are free to "re-arrange" as they see fit (I guess usually due to using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) datastructure to store key-value pairs).

Is there any need for keeping them in a specific order? Could you sort keys alphabetically yourself if you need for example a consistent hash of the document? If the order is important to you then you'd need to store them as an array of `{"key": "key_value", "value": "value_value"}` [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) but I doubt you want to go down this route.

A final option is to store the origial order of keys as a field in the document itself under a key like `_key`. The datatype could be an array of strings. But JSON isn't realy meant to care about the order.